# My HTML is rusty but I'm pretty sure something is wrong

Tags: html, margin

so i've been having a really tough time after a month away from HTML, not much whatsoever, however I seem to have lost the knack with something, and that's getting my div/any html element to not be a few pixels from top of a page and even with a fixed div, it is still around 8 pixels away from the top and left of my page and I have no idea what is going on.  There's no padding, no margin, nothing like this and I am utterly perplexed at why this is happening.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            CrystalBallStories
        </title>
        <link rel=stylesheet link="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="screen">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main">
            <nav id="nav">
                <div class="nav_opt">
                    Home
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is the HTML and the CSS is:

```
html
{
font-family:Corbel, 'Lucida Grande', Helvetica, sans-serif;
background: rgb(69,72,77); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(69,72,77,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(69,72,77,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(69,72,77,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(69,72,77,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(69,72,77,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(69,72,77,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#45484d', endColorstr='#000000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
width: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}

#main
{ 
background-color:#000000;
position:fixed;
height:98%;
width:80%;
color:#DDDDDD;
overflow-y:scroll;
text-wrap:break-word;
margin-left:10%;
margin-right:10%;
border-top-left-radius:30px;
border-top-right-radius:10px;
}

#nav
{
background-color:rgba(69,72,77,0.8);
height:8%;

}
```

This used to all work for me before but it is, for some reason, a little away from the top and left as I said before, as can be seen on the site: http://www.crystallballstories.com

Any help is appreciated as this is driving me insane!

Answer (score 2):

```
html,body{margin:0}
```

Problem solved.

Comment: Wow, I remember struggling before and feeling like hitting myself with a mallet...Thank you so much!  Back to the malletboard.